# CosmosDB partition key / unique key confusion

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I created CosmosDB named DB1 in Azure.

#### READING 1

1. Created container1 with /category as partition key and NO unique key.
2. Added these records: # in 2nd record, I supplied no ID and one was created for me.

```
 {
        "id": "1",
        "category": "Personal",
        "name": "Record1"
 }

 {
    "name": "Record3",
    "category": "Personal",
 }
```

3. Successful data entry -

#### READING 2

1. Created container2 with /id as partition key and /category as unique
2. Tried to add these 3 records.

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "category": "Personal",
        "name": "Record1"
}

{
        "category": "Business",
        "name": "Record2",
        "priority": "high"
}

{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Record3"
}
```

3. Record 3 (id=1, name=record3) couldn't be inserted since I guess id=1 is taken already??

#### READING 3

1. Created container2 with /id as partition key and NO uniq key
2. Added these records

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "category": "Personal",
        "name": "Record1"
}

{
        "category": "Business",
        "name": "Record2"
}

{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Record3"
}
```

3. The third record could not be inserted since id=1 already exists in record1.

NOW

MY question is this.

In reading1, the partition key was /category and yet it allowed me to insert two records with same category and yet in reading3 when /id was made partition key, it did not allow me to add two records with same id.

WHY? Been trying to figure that out. anyone?

Comment: Just saw that the question format was all out of whack - fixed so its readable now.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your specific questions, there are few things I would like to mention:

- A document has to be unique in a logical partition i.e. combination of `id` field and the partition key value has to be unique in a container.
- If you do not assign a value to the `id` field, SDK can assign a value to that field.

Now coming to your questions:

- In your first scenario, since the partition key values are different you are able to create 2 documents. If you query the 2nd document, you should actually see an id being assigned to your document.
- In your third scenario, since the `id` attribute is the partition key, the insertion failed because your record 1 and 3 have the same partition key/id value combination.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am trying to make sense of it. So you said the "combination" of id and partition-key uniquely identifies a record?  Did I understand that right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Only older SDK's assigned id. The new ones like .NET v3 do not.

Comment: @MarkBrown - Thanks. I didn’t know that.